# Where can I find Mandrake 7.0 ISO?

Tags: linux, iso

I'm on the look out for Mandrake 7.0 ISO but I can't find it anywhere. Anyone have it? I need the i586 version.

Comment: Mandrake 7.0? What you need it for?

Answer (score 6):

7.1 is located at ftp://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/mandriva-prehistory/iso/7.1/i586/

for 7.0 an network install image is available at ftp://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/mandriva-prehistory/7.0/images/

maybe ftp://ftp.orst.edu/pub/mirrors/linux_mirrors/mandrake/iso/mandrake70.iso is the image you are looking for?

Comment: I did have a look at distib-coffe before but what i really want is a complete iso. The last ftp site doesn't work for me. I guess you mean oregonstate.edu but the folders ain't there either.